# How can I prevent from my Android app from running this method too often?

Tags: java, android

```
public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values) {
    synchronized (this) {
        //this method runs too often!!
    }
}
```

How can I prevent this method from running too often?  What I want to do is, once this method runs, this method will not run again for the next 1 second?

Comment: it is part of my Android application that implements SensorListener~

Comment: So that method doesn't run too often, it runs exactly when it should. The problem is you have some heavy-weight (slow) code attached to it. You should check ElapsedTime since the last call and only invoke your real method every 1 second, otherwise return.

Answer (score 2):

You are listening for updates from a sensor. When you register to listen with [`SensorManager.registerListener()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#registerListener%28android.hardware.SensorEventListener,%20android.hardware.Sensor,%20int%29) you specify a rate parameter. Try setting this to [`SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorManager.html#SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL) for the lowest update rate, which should be quite suitable. If it's too slow you're doing too much work in your method.

Answer (score 1):

Sensor event do have a timestamp information. Store the timestamp of the last time you run the method. Ignore the forthcoming events until they reaches the previous timestamp plus the desired threshold (separation).

I mean this:

```
long tsLastEvent = 0;
long thresholdEvent = 1000000;

public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    synchronized (this) {
        if (event.timestamp > tsLastEvent + thresholdEvent) {
             tsLastEvent = event.timestamp;
             // ... dealing with the event ...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, then is the new method going to look like this?

public void onSensorChanged(int sensor, float[] values, SensorEvent event)

Answer (score 0):

Hey that thing we cannot customize....but i suggest you to keep long value with in the scope that can be accessible from onSensorChanged() method....so once you execute it before save the current time in milliseconds and again if the method is invoked just compare the previously when it is called and if the value is less than 1 sec... don't execute the code